# On libxml, how can I get this property value?

Tags: xml, libxml2

For an XML that has

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<COLLADA version="1.4.0" xmlns="http://www.collada.org/2005/11/COLLADASchema">
 <library_geometries>
  <geometry id="Cube">
   <mesh>
    <source id="Cube">
     <float_array count="24" ">1 2 3</float_array>
[..]
```

I'm getting properly "1 2 3" string with a

```
if (!xmlStrcmp(cur_node->name, (const xmlChar *) "mesh")
    printf(": %s\n",xmlNodeGetContent(cur_node->children->next);
```

But how do I get the value of 'count'? ("count="24"")

e.g.

```
printf(": %s\n", xmlGetProp(cur_node->children->next,(const xmlChar *)"count"));
```

isn't right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `xmlNodeGetContent` is

> Read the value of a node, this can be
>   either the text carried directly by
>   this node if it's a TEXT node or the
>   aggregate string of the values carried
>   by this node child's (TEXT and
>   ENTITY_REF). Entity references are
>   substituted.

Thus what's happening is that `cur_node->children->next` actually points at the `<source>` node, not the `<float_array...` node.  The call to `xmlNodeGetContent` **appears** to work because it's fetching the content from the contained node.

The call to `xmlGetProp` returns nothing because you're invoking it on the wrong node. 
You need to ensure that you are invoking `xmlGetProp` on the correct node.